# Return a subset of Array using index C#

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, subset

What is the best way to return a subset of a C# array given a fromIndex and toIndex?

Obviously I can use a loop but are there other approaches?

This is the method signature I am looking to fill.

```
public static FixedSizeList<T> FromExisting(FixedSizeList<T> fixedSizeList, Int32 fromIndex, Int32 toIndex)
```

FixedSizeList internal implementation is

```
private T[] _Array;
this._Array = new T[size];
```

Comment: lol, yeah just noticed that myself. Generics hurts my brain...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myArray.Skip(fromIndex).Take(toIndex - fromIndex + 1);
```

EDIT:
The result of Skip and Take are IEnumerable and the count will be zero until you actually use it.

if you try

```
        int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] subset = myArray.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray();
```

subset will be {3, 4}

Comment: I actually liked this approach more then all of them but am failing to get it working. Skip() no matter what I pass in returns 0 items... Must be doing something wrong... hmmmm

Comment: @Maxim you could try adding .ToArray() to the expression.

Comment: Got ya... Didn't catch on that I was dealing with IEnumerable... Thanks again mate :-)

Comment: I found that I need the following to make this work: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 3):

List Already has a `CopyTo`  Method which should do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eb2b9x8.aspx

This is the Signature of the method:

```
public void CopyTo( int index, T[] array, int arrayIndex,   int count )
```

Answer (score 3):

`Array.Copy` will do [what you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx).